# Ionic controller reloading on $state.go with param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic application that has multiple tabs. To navigate between tabs I use

```
$state.go('tabname',{params:params})
```

This is all working fine however if I pass a paramater into $state.go it reloads the whole angular controller.

I put a console.log at the top of my angular controller. This logs out when the tab is first loaded (fine) then if I navigate to another tab then navigate back it does not log (fine) but if i navigate to another tab and call

```
$state.go('tabname', {paramKey:'paramValue'})
```

it logs (not fine) telling me that the controller thats associated with that tab is being reloaded. This is causing me lots of issues. Is there any way of telling the view not to reload the controller?

Here is the $stateProvider .state for the tab in question:

```
.state('tab.ask', {
    url: '/ask',
    views: {
        'tab-ask': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-ask.html',
            controller: 'AskCtrl'
        }
    },
    params: {
        'paramKey': null
    }
})
```

Comment: Try adding cache:true, object in the state of tab 

Ref: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Are you sure `$scope.on` is what you want? Imo it should be `$scope.$on`, second, why don't you use the `ui-sref` directive or the `$state.go` function?

Comment: Adding cache:true did not solve the issue (It says in the documentation that the default value for caching is true anyway). I put the wrong code in my question the function call I actually use is $state.go() I have updated my question

Comment: Have you tried using `$state.transitionTo('tabname', {paramKey: 'paramValue'}, {notify: false})` ?

Comment: Just tried transitionTo with notify:flase that does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no way to tell controller to  NOT reload on the state change. As far as I know that is basically how angular works-data binding and so on. Meaning, all the values in the controller are not available to current scope and a scope is initiated for the current view.

The best way to store values without using cache is using `$services` asit follows `Singletons design pattern` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and the values passed to the services are not changed even when controllers are reloaded.

You can find an example on how to create services on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_services.htm.

You need to update the services each time any event(on tab) so that you can keep track of which page you are on.

Good luck.